# Powershell scripts will not work with Jenkins plugin on Windows

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm writing some pretty simple scripts in Powershell 32-bit and they are working fine.

For instance, I want to open internet explorer to a webpage and start typing in keys. The following code works fine when I run it in powershell ISE.

```
Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$url = "http://WebAddress"
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate($url)

sleep 30

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{2}{tab}{H}{E}{L}{L}{O}")
```

I have downloaded a [Windows PowerShell plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin) and have executed the same code through it and received the following errors:

```
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\Jenkins Test
[Jenkins Test] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson257018662776252417.ps1'"
New-Object : Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {0002DF01-000
0-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following er
ror: 80004005.
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson257018662776252417.ps1:4 char:17
+ $ie = New-Object <<<<  -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman 
   ds.NewObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson257018662776252417.ps1:5 char:13
+ $ie.Navigate <<<< ($url)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Navigate:String) [], RuntimeE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


Exception calling "SendWait" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied"
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson257018662776252417.ps1:9 char:42
+ [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait <<<< ("{2}{tab}{H}{E}{L}{L}{O}")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Is there a reason why my code will not work through Jenkins like it does in Powershell? I tried some simple echo scripts which worked fine, but any more complex and it throws an error.

Comment: There might be dependencies which are missing on your build server causing these errors.

Comment: What user are you using to run the jenkins agent, lack of permission can cause issues. COM objects have other permissions associated with them as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this Anthony? I'm a bit new to Jenkins and how to start remedying the situation.

Comment: Hi James, I'm using the admin, so I should have no issues with permissions should I?

Comment: @LeChuck So the jenkins service is running as admin in the services TAB? The application error seems like the COM object is not registered to this specific account.

Comment: So I need to register the COM object to the Jenkins admin account? Can this be done within Jenkins?

Comment: The Jenkins process will be running as a specific user (by default this might be the local system account, this is why you might be having issues as this is not the same as a user account.) You will need to log-on to the windows machines as the user account that jenkins is running as, a google for registering COM objects might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set execution policy once: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849812.aspx

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Run PowerShell as admin and run that command. There may be security concerns using Unrestricted. But if it works, read the link above and find the policy that works best in your context. Options are (copy/pasted from the link):

- **Restricted**. Does not load configuration files or run scripts. Restricted is the default execution policy.
- **AllSigned**. Requires that all scripts and configuration files be signed by a trusted publisher, including scripts that you write on
  the local computer.
- **RemoteSigned**. Requires that all scripts and configuration files downloaded from the Internet be signed by a trusted publisher.
- **Unrestricted**. Loads all configuration files and runs all scripts. If you run an unsigned script that was downloaded from the Internet,
  you are prompted for permission before it runs.
- **Bypass**. Nothing is blocked and there are no warnings or prompts.
- **Undefined**. Removes the currently assigned execution policy from the current scope. This parameter will not remove an execution policy
  that is set in a Group Policy scope.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the plugin sets ExecutionPolicy=Bypass... So this must not be it. Perhaps it's that they also automatically run it non-interactive. Perhaps interactive is required for this script?